# Not able to allow null values in my sql script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm very beginner in writing sql scripts,

while trying to write the following script and execute it, i could not send null values into the procedure.

could someone help me out from the following code??

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_TALKTRACK2 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @city VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @state VARCHAR(100)= NULL,
    @zip VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @gender  VARCHAR(100)= NULL



AS
BEGIN
    /*
    DECLARE @CITY VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @STATE VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @ZIP VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @GENDER  VARCHAR(100) */
    DECLARE @TOTALMAKES INT
    DECLARE @DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @MAKE2 INT 

    SET @CITY = @city
    SET @STATE = @state
    SET @ZIP = @zip
    SET @GENDER = @gender 


    SET @DESCRIPTION =  ' MAKES ARE BEING USED IN ' + @CITY + ' ' + @STATE + ' ' + @ZIP


    SET @MAKE2 = (SELECT COUNT(MAKE)FROM [TALK TRACK RAP].[DBO].[CARSEXCEL] 
    WHERE CITY = @CITY AND STATE = @STATE AND ZIP = @ZIP AND GENDER = @GENDER)



    SELECT  MAKE , ( (100 * COUNT(*)) /@MAKE2 ) AS MAKECOUNT , 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( (100 * COUNT(*)) /@MAKE2 ))+ ' % ' + MAKE + @DESCRIPTION AS MAKES_PERCENTAGE INTO ##TEMP1
      FROM [TALK TRACK RAP].[DBO].[CARSEXCEL] 
      WHERE CITY = @CITY AND STATE = @STATE AND ZIP = @ZIP AND GENDER = @GENDER
      GROUP BY MAKE 


    SELECT * FROM ##TEMP1 where MAKECOUNT <> 0 order by MAKECOUNT desc

    DROP TABLE ##TEMP1

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

END
GO
```

In the above if i execute leaving one parameter i'm getting null records because i don't have null data

```
EXEC SP_TALKTRACK2 @CITY = 'ODESSA', @STATE = 'TX', @ZIP = '79762', @GENDER = 'FEMALE'
```

But what i need is, it should ignore that parameter and run considering only the other 3 values or 2 values what ever i provide.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ISNULL if first parameter is null then return secound parameter
for for example ISNULL(@CITY, '') if @CITY is null return empty string becuase secound parameter is empty string
this check is required becuse if you add null to string the result is null!

and also in where condation you must check if @city is null dont check city column by null 
like :

```
@City is null or City = @City
```

if your City column also is nullable you can check this :

```
((@City is null AND City is null) OR (City = @City))
```

and you'r procedure must like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_TALKTRACK2 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @city VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @state VARCHAR(100)= NULL,
    @zip VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @gender  VARCHAR(100)= NULL



AS
BEGIN
    /*
    DECLARE @CITY VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @STATE VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @ZIP VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @GENDER  VARCHAR(100) */
    DECLARE @TOTALMAKES INT
    DECLARE @DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @MAKE2 INT 

    SET @CITY = @city
    SET @STATE = @state
    SET @ZIP = @zip
    SET @GENDER = @gender 


    SET @DESCRIPTION =  ' MAKES ARE BEING USED IN ' + ISNULL(@CITY, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(@STATE, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(@ZIP, '')


    SET @MAKE2 = (SELECT COUNT(MAKE)FROM [TALK TRACK RAP].[DBO].[CARSEXCEL] 
    WHERE (@city is null OR CITY = @CITY) AND (@state is null or [STATE] = @STATE) AND (@zip is null or ZIP = @ZIP) AND (@gender is null or GENDER = @GENDER))



    SELECT  MAKE , ( (100 * COUNT(*)) /@MAKE2 ) AS MAKECOUNT , 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( (100 * COUNT(*)) /@MAKE2 ))+ ' % ' + MAKE + @DESCRIPTION AS MAKES_PERCENTAGE INTO ##TEMP1
      FROM [TALK TRACK RAP].[DBO].[CARSEXCEL] 
      WHERE  (@city is null OR CITY = @CITY) AND (@state is null or [STATE] = @STATE) AND (@zip is null or ZIP = @ZIP) AND (@gender is null or GENDER = @GENDER)
      GROUP BY MAKE 


    SELECT * FROM ##TEMP1 where MAKECOUNT <> 0 order by MAKECOUNT desc

    DROP TABLE ##TEMP1

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

END
GO
```

Comment: please mark accept answer, instead of comment if, give your answer, or if it is helpful answer please upvote it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your condition you must use following format :

```
Where ISNULL(CITY,-1) = ISNULL(@CITY,-1)
```

OR

```
Where ((City is null and @City is null) or (city = @City))
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL `null` is something of a Pandora's box.  So let me introduce you to some of `null` fun.

If you **add** `null` to anything, the resulting sum is `null`.  For example,

```
print 'Hello ' + null
```

Prints the string `Hello` plus `null`, which is `null`.  The `print` statement will not print anything, not even an empty row.

If you **compare** `null` to anything, the result is not `true` or `false`, but a third value: `unknown`.  The SQL standard tries to make `unknown` intuitive, but it can have surprising effects.  For example, the query

```
select  *
from    users
where   name = null
```

will never return a row, not even a row where the value of the name column is actually `null`.  Not even `null` is equal to `null`:

```
where   null = null
```

will happily filter out all rows.  There is a special operator you can use to find columns that are `null`:

```
where   name is null
```

Beside `is null`, you can use `isnull()` or `coalesce()` to deal with `null` values.  Both of these functions allow you to provide an alternative for `null`:

```
 print 'Hello ' + isnull(@name, 'unknown human')
```

If the `@name` variable is `null`, the `isnull()` function will return `'unknown human'` instead.

Using this information, you can ignore `null` filter parameters by explicitly looking for them:

```
where   @name is null or name = name
```

Alternatively, there is a common trick to return any row if `@name` is not set:

```
where   name = isnull(@name, name)
```

When `@name` is `null`, the result of `isnull(@name, name)` is `name`, and `name = name` is true.

One of the more surprising aspects of `null` involves the `not in` operator. Look at this query:

```
select  *
from    names
where   name not in (select name from actor)
```

Now imagine that the `actor` table contains these rows:

```
'Barrack'
'Vladimir'
null
```

Then the `where` clause above becomes:

```
where   name not in ('Barrack', 'Vladimir', null)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
where   name <> 'Barrack' and name <> 'Vladimir' and name <> null
```

The surprise is this: `name <> null` evaluates to `unknown`, and `true and unknown` is also  `unknown`.  So this query, which looks like it just excludes Barrack and Vladimir, excludes everyone instead.  It never returns a row.

For some more funs with `null`, enjoy [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).